# Iterate pixels in filled circle counter-clockwise starting from center

Tags: geometry

I am trying to make a visual effect where a circle is gradually drawn one pixel at a time, starting from the center. Imagine a filled circle with radius = r. Iterate all pixels in the circle starting at center = (centerX, centerY). Next pixel (centerX + 1, centerY), and now iterate pixels of inner circle with r = 1 in a counter-clockwise manner. When coming back round to (centerX + 1, centerY), instead go to next innermost circle with r = 2, so (centerX + 2, centerY) and so on until all pixels of the filled circle has been iterated.

Would iterating all pixels in all inner circles (not filled) cover all pixels of the filled circle? If so, how can I iterate the pixels in an inner circle counter-clockwise?